# loop for array of images and audio

Tags: android, audio

I am making an app in which there are many images and audio. All I want to do is apply a loop for these images and audio so that when an image gets displayed the audio will get played, i.e. image1=audio1, image2=audio2. There are next and previous buttons in my app. Next will display the next image and audio, previous will display previous one. Should I use a for loop? or switch case? I have tried this code. But when the images and audio array comes to an end I want to start all over again. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


int i=1;
MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
int image = 0;
int sound ;
int [] sounds;
int [] audio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    sounds = new int [] {
            R.raw.audio_one, R.raw.audio_two, R.raw.audio_three, R.raw.audio_four
    };
    mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[0]);
    mediaplayer.start();


    final int [] images = {
            R.drawable.num1, R.drawable.num2, R.drawable.num3, R.drawable.num4
    };

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton prev = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    final ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    final ImageView img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(image==3){

            }
            else {
                image++;
            }

            i=image;



            audio(i);
            mediaplayer.start();

            img1.setImageResource(images[image]);

        }

    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (image<=0){
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.num1);



            }
            else
            {
                image--;

            }

            i=image;

            audio(i);

            mediaplayer.start();

            img1.setImageResource(images[image]);
        }
    });
}

public void audio(int a)
{


    mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[a]);

    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code...

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(image== images.lenght()-1){
                   image=0;
            }
            else {
                image++;
            }

            i=image;



            audio(i);
            mediaplayer.start();

            img1.setImageResource(images[image]);

        }

    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (image==0){

                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.num1);



            }
            else
            {
                image--;

            }

            i=image;

            audio(i);

            mediaplayer.start();

            img1.setImageResource(images[image]);
        }
    });
```

}